# Modify persistent JPA object

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity student with details, how do l allow an update of existing data and keep track of changes made on the object?

```
Student oldStudent = new Student()
oldStudent.getStudent(id);
Copy contents of old student, and save them on an amendment entity
Then update the oldstudent and save it as the new referenced entity.
```

Help will be appreciated on how to go about this using jpa.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a apache library for copying:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

```
  copyProperties(Object o1, Object o2)
```

this will copy all fields from current object to update object..